# How to Animate button within screen range

Tags: android, button

I am have an app where you click on a button and it will translate to another point on the screen.

Here is what I use for translating.

```
findViewById(R.id.clickButton).animate().translationX((float) (Math.random() * ( 100 - 400 )));
findViewById(R.id.clickButton).animate().translationY((float) (Math.random() * ( 100 - 400 )));
```

It is good however the button may translate partially out of the screen and sometimes on top of other widgets. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

To get Math.random() value in a range that you want, you will need to add this -:

```
 bttn1.animate().translationX((float) (randomFromInterval(100,800)));
 bttn2.animate().translationY((float) (randomFromInterval(200,500)));

 public int randomFromInterval(int from,int to)
 {
    return (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
 }
```

And if you are getting your buttons on top of other widgets then you will have to place buttons at the end of your relative layout because it manages the views z-axis visibility according to the widgets you have written in xml layout for example -:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In above layout button3 is the toppest view from z-axis if you need to make button1 the toppest view from z-axis then you will have rearranged your code like this -:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this explanation clears your doubt.